# Chrome --headless for AWS Lambda?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chromium

Chrome with headless mode already available for linux:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

It works only with Canary right now, but it coming official in Chrome 57.

Any chances to run Google Chrome on aws lambda?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing. I took a crack at it but it doesn't seem to work quite right yet. My progress is here: https://github.com/adieuadieu/thingamajigs/tree/master/serverless-chrome-pdf There's also a thread on this topic here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/headless-dev/qqbZVZ2IwEw/Wr9wmgb1EQAJ

Answer (score 16):

Yes; it's possible.

Compiling a non-debug build of [Headless Chrome](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/) yields a binary that's ~125 MB, and just under 44 MB when gzipped. This means it fits within the 250 MB uncompressed and 50 MB size [limitation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) for the function's deployment package.

What's (currently) required is to force Chrome to compile without using shared memory at /dev/shm. Theres a thread on the topic on the [headless-dev](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/headless-dev) google group [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/headless-dev/qqbZVZ2IwEw/CPInd55OBgAJ).

Here are steps I've used to build a binary of headless Chrome that will work on AWS Lambda. They're based on [this](http://www.zackarychapple.guru/chrome/2016/08/24/chrome-headless.html) and [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md).

1. Create a new EC2 instance using the community AMI with name amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.3.x86_64-gp2 (us-west-2 ami-7172b611).
2. Pick an Instance Type with at least 16 GB of memory. Compile time will take about 4-5 hours on a t2.xlarge, or 2-3ish on a t2.2xlarge or about 45 min on a c4.4xlarge.
3. Give yourself a Root Volume that's at least 30 GB (40 GB if you want to compile a debug build—which you won't be able to upload to Lambda because it's too big.)
4. SSH into the new instance and run:

```bash
sudo printf "LANG=en_US.utf-8\nLC_ALL=en_US.utf-8" >> /etc/environment
sudo yum install -y git redhat-lsb python bzip2 tar pkgconfig atk-devel alsa-lib-devel bison binutils brlapi-devel bluez-libs-devel bzip2-devel cairo-devel cups-devel dbus-devel dbus-glib-devel expat-devel fontconfig-devel freetype-devel gcc-c++ GConf2-devel glib2-devel glibc.i686 gperf glib2-devel gtk2-devel gtk3-devel java-1.*.0-openjdk-devel libatomic libcap-devel libffi-devel libgcc.i686 libgnome-keyring-devel libjpeg-devel libstdc++.i686 libX11-devel libXScrnSaver-devel libXtst-devel libxkbcommon-x11-devel ncurses-compat-libs nspr-devel nss-devel pam-devel pango-devel pciutils-devel pulseaudio-libs-devel zlib.i686 httpd mod_ssl php php-cli python-psutil wdiff --enablerepo=epel
```

*Yum* will complain about some packages not existing. Whatever. I haven't looked into them. Didn't seem to stop me from building headless_shell, though. Ignore whiney little *Yum* and move on. Next:

```bash
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/depot_tools" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
mkdir Chromium && cd Chromium
fetch --no-history chromium
cd src
```

At this point we need to make a very small change to the Chrome code. By default on Linux, Chrome assumes there to be a tmpfs at `/dev/shm`. There is no tmpfs available to a Lambda function. :-(

The file we have to change is `src/base/files/file_util_posix.cc`. Modify `GetShmemTempDir()` such that it always returns the OSs temp dir (`/tmp`). A simple way to do this is to just remove the entire `#if defined(OS_LINUX)` block in the `GetShmemTempDir()` function. A less drastic change is to hardcode `use_dev_shm` to `false`:

```cc
bool GetShmemTempDir(bool executable, FilePath* path) {
#if defined(OS_LINUX)
  bool use_dev_shm = true;
  if (executable) {
    static const bool s_dev_shm_executable = DetermineDevShmExecutable();
    use_dev_shm = s_dev_shm_executable;
  }

// cuz lambda
use_dev_shm = false; // <-- add this. Yes it's pretty hack-y

  if (use_dev_shm) {
    *path = FilePath("/dev/shm");
    return true;
  }
#endif
  return GetTempDir(path);
}
```

With that change, it's time to compile. Picking things back up in the `src` directory, set some compile arguments and then (the last command) start the build process.

```bash
mkdir -p out/Headless
echo 'import("//build/args/headless.gn")' > out/Headless/args.gn
echo 'is_debug = false' >> out/Headless/args.gn
echo 'symbol_level = 0' >> out/Headless/args.gn
echo 'is_component_build = false' >> out/Headless/args.gn
echo 'remove_webcore_debug_symbols = true' >> out/Headless/args.gn
echo 'enable_nacl = false' >> out/Headless/args.gn
gn gen out/Headless
ninja -C out/Headless headless_shell
```

Finally we make a tarball of the relevant file(s) we'll need to run in Lambda.

```bash
mkdir out/headless-chrome && cd out
cp Headless/headless_shell Headless/libosmesa.so headless-chrome/
tar -zcvf chrome-headless-lambda-linux-x64.tar.gz headless-chrome/
```

Within Lambda, run `headless_shell` with the remote debugger interface enabled by executing:

```bash
/path/to/headless_shell --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data --single-process --data-path=/tmp/data-path --homedir=/tmp --disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir
```

Since /tmp is the only writeable place in a Lambda function, there are a bunch of flags just telling Chrome where to dump it's data. They're not necessary but it keeps Chrome happy. Note also that it's been [mentioned](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/headless-dev/qqbZVZ2IwEw/XMKlEMP3EQAJ) that with the `--disable-gpu` flag, we don't need `libosmesa.so`, the omission of which would shave off about 4 MB from our package zip.

I've started [this](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome) project with the aim of making it easier to get started. It comes with a pre-built headless Chrome binary which you can get [here](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/tree/master/chrome).

Comment: No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.

Comment: getting the above error, tried with --no-sandbox but it timed out